# 3rd view control with NSstring and "Zeros"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am having issues with zero's

If my stings contain zeros or nothing the 3rd control view crashed the app.

Any ideas

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    appDelegate= (TemplateIponeAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        mailButton.enabled = YES;

    rResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.RCount];
    bResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"B Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.BCount];
    pResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"P Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.PCount];
    fResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"F Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.FCount];

    totalResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"Total R-P-B:  %d",appDelegate.TotalPressed];

    rightCount = appDelegate.RCount + appDelegate.BCount+appDelegate.PCount;

    grandtotal.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"Total :  %d",rightCount];

    ratiocount= (appDelegate.RCount + appDelegate.BCount+appDelegate.PCount) /appDelegate.FCount;   
    ratiototal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:  @"Total :  %d",appDelegate.FCount];

    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line,

```
ratiocount= (appDelegate.RCount + appDelegate.BCount+appDelegate.PCount) /appDelegate.FCount;
```

if `appDelegate.FCount` is zero, then this will result in an error. You should put some kind of a check on it.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed the offending lines of code and still it crashes.  I am beginning to wonder if it has something to do with the fact I do not have any anything loaded into the appDelegate.